# Circular warnings about Swift static override being final

Tags: swift, appkit, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

I have an `NSDocumentController` subclass that needs to know if it has restored any windows via the `NSWindowRestoration` protocol.

The particular function I'm overriding, [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowrestoration/1526251-restorewindow), to do this is:

```
override open static func restoreWindow(withIdentifier identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier, state: NSCoder, completionHandler: @escaping (NSWindow?, Error?) -> Void)
```

As written, this function is called exactly when I'd like and works perfectly. However, I get the following warning:

```
Static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
```

This warning includes a seemingly helpful fixit, to transform that `open` into `public`. But, when I accept, I then get this error:

```
Overriding static method must be as accessible as the declaration it overrides
```

This error suggests I replace `public` with `open`.

I've opened a radar with Apple about this circular behavior. But, I'd really like to find a way to quiet this warning. Alternatively, perhaps there's another way for an NSDocumentController subclass to be informed that it has restored windows.

To reproduce this error, create a new App project with Xcode 10, and include the following code. I just threw it in after the `AppDelegate` declaration. By default, the project is configured with Swift 4.2 and builds for macOS 10.14.

```
class MyDocumentController: NSDocumentController {
    override open static func restoreWindow(withIdentifier identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier, state: NSCoder, completionHandler: @escaping (NSWindow?, Error?) -> Void) {
        super.restoreWindow(withIdentifier: identifier, state: state, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not get a warning with `override public static` in Xcode 10.1 – can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: According to https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8673, this has been fixed.

Comment: That's the one! And that issue also includes a workaround. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Martin R above for the link to the issue in the Swift compiler. That issue also has a workaround, that does indeed fix the issue for me.

> Fixing this is possible by actually using class instead of static in the override in class Y.